# How to solve "FileNotFoundException was unhandled"?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I have been trying to use EmguCV v3.0 on Visual Studio 2012 and C# to Covert Image Format from IplImage to Bitmap. When I debug project, the VS throw a following exception:

> Could not load file or Assembly “Emgu.CV, Version=2.4.10.1939,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438”....

I have checked the system environment path and Project's References and using in project, there are correct. Then I have also tried to change Platform target to AnyCPU, failed!
I don't know what's wrong with my project, please help, Thanks!
 [image]

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using Emgu.CV;
> using Emgu.Util;
> using Emgu.CV.UI;
> using Emgu.CV.Structure;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Drawing.Imaging;
> using Cognex.VisionPro;
> using Cognex.VisionPro.Display;
> using Cognex.VisionPro.ImageFile;
> using Cognex.VisionPro.OCRMax;
> using System.Xml;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
> using System.Diagnostics;
> ```

```
namespace dfadvocrkernel {
     public class dfadvocrdecode
     { 
         public unsafe Int32 DF_ADVOCRDecode(void* inBMP, void* inPara, void* pResult)
             {
                 IntPtr inputBmp = new IntPtr((IntPtr *)inBMP);
                 Image<Gray, byte> dest = new Image<Gray, byte>(CvInvoke.cvGetSize(inputBmp));
                 CvInvoke.cvCopy(inputBmp, dest, IntPtr.Zero);
                 Bitmap bmp = dest.ToBitmap();
                  ....
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: If you find the Dlls on your machine in file explorer, did you "unlock" them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to confirm whether it was unlocked. can you tell me? Thank you

Comment: You just look at its properties. If it is, then you would see a button to do that.

Comment: I have looked at its properties, But didn't find Unlock button. Does that mean this file is unlocked?